# regular expression to find local telephone numbers doesn't work

Tags: python, regex

I commented right in front of the conditions what kind of local phone number it should correspond to.

```
enter code here

        if re.match(r"^(\+225)\d{8}", line):  # +22588241628
            count += 1
        elif re.match(r"^(\+225)\s\d{8}", line):  # +225 88241628
            count += 1
        elif re.match(r"^(\+225)\s\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}\s\d{2}", line): # +225 88 24 16 28
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: What doesn't work is the pattern while I tested it on https://regexr.com/

Comment: I think it works. See a short example https://ideone.com/56WpgV

Comment: it doesn't work with this for example "TEL;X-Autre:+22548346583"

Comment: That is because you are using [re.match](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) Use re.search and remove the anchor `^` like `if re.search(r"(\+225)\d{8}", line):`

Comment: ah yes it's true thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the regex:

```
\+?225[-.\s|]?(\d{8}|\d{2}[-.\s]\d{2}[-.\s]\d{2}[-.\s]\d{2})
```

```
\+?        <- One or Zero +
225        <- must be exact
[-.\s|]?   <- On or Zero symbols of:   -.\s|    ( \s is a space)

Now there is an OR statement
(A|B)       <-- A or B
A =  \d{8}  <-- 8 digital characters after each other
B =  \d{2}[-.\s]\d{2}[-.\s]\d{2}[-.\s]\d{2}   <-- 2 digits  
                                                  a seperator -. or \s
                                                  2 digits 
                                                  a seperator -. or \s
                                                  2 digits 
                                                  a seperator -. or \s
                                                  2 digits
```

Comment: Yes it works but it also works for +221 or +223 I want it to be limited only to the number starting with +225

Comment: thank a lot it works perfectly you're a killer